# How to prove this inclusion (for continuity of a function)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In order to prove the continuity of the function $f$ given by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ on $(R,|\cdot|)$

I want to prove that $$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists r>0, ]x-r,x+r[\subset f^{-1}(]f(x)-\varepsilon , f(x)+\varepsilon[)$$

I take y from the first set and tried to prove that:

$$\frac{1}{y^2+1}\in (]f(x)-\varepsilon , f(x)+\varepsilon[) $$

but I don't know how to finish

Comment: Do you mind proving it in another way? Or you want to prove it using only this way?

Comment: only this way @Fareed AF

Comment: You realize this is just a twisted way of proving the classical $\epsilon,\delta$ presentation (with $r$ instead of $\delta$). So why not study $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le \dfrac{|x-x_0||x+x_0|}{(x^2+1)(x_0^2+1}|$ for $x_0\in(x-r,x+r)$. Go for two cases, $|x|<1$ and $|x|>1$ which lead to two different ways of bounding this inequality.

Comment: I just realized it thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $f(y) \in (]f(x)-\varepsilon , f(x)+\varepsilon[)$ is the same as proving $|f(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ and given that $|y-x|<r$

Now it is a bit easier to prove it,

$\begin{align}
|f(y) - f(x)| 
&= \left|\frac1{1 + y^2} - \frac1{1 + x^2}\right|
\\&= \left|  \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(1 + y^2)(1 + x^2)}\right|
\\&= |y - x| \frac{|y + x|}{(1 + y^2)(1 + x^2)}
\\&≤ |y - x| \frac{|y| + |x|}{(1 + y^2)(1 + x^2)}
\\&= |y - x| \left[\frac{|y|}{(1 + y^2)(1 + x^2)} + \frac{|x|}{(1 + y^2)(1 + x^2)}\right]
\\&≤ |y-x|\left[\frac{|y|}{(1 + y^2)} +\frac{|x|}{(1 + x^2)}\right]
\\&≤ 2|y-x| <2r
\end{align}$

Take $r=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$